# What is this function doing calling itself from within?

Tags: javascript

Below given function is JS sorting function based on multiple criteria. I found this cool function on some website. It would be great if someone could explain this function to me.

I am unable to understand the last part of it, where it is calling itself with another parentheses given a & b variables inside it. **sortbyMultipleKeys(keys.slice(1))(a, b)**

calling a function this way; totally new to me f()(a,b) <-- Howwwwwwwwwww??? :|.

I would highly appreciate if anyone could explain it with some examples. :)

```js
var obj = [
  {alpha: 'c',year: 2002},
  {alpha: 'b',year: 2004},
  {alpha: 'a',year: 2004},
  {alpha: 'd',year: 2003},
  {alpha: 'a',year: 2002},
  {alpha: 'c',year: 2004},
  {alpha: 'd',year: 2001},
  {alpha: 'b',year: 2002},
  {alpha: 'a',year: 2003},
  {alpha: 'b',year: 2002},
  {alpha: 'd',year: 2001},
  {alpha: 'c',year: 2004}
];

function sortbyMultipleKeys(keys) {
  return function(a, b) {
    if (keys.length == 0) return;
    key = keys[0];
    if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
    else if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
    else return sortbyMultipleKeys(keys.slice(1))(a, b);
  }
}

let a = obj.sort(sortbyMultipleKeys(["alpha", "year"]));

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

What's special about JavaScript, is the fact that you can return a function *from* a function.

```js
function foo(){
  return function() { console.log('Hello!'); }
}

console.log(foo()); //prints function bar () { console.log('Hello') }

foo()(); //prints Hello!
```

So what `sortbyMultipleKeys(keys.slice(1))(a, b)` is essentially doing, is calling a function that was returned from the `sortbyMultipleKeys` function.

```
function sortbyMultipleKeys(keys) {
  return function(a, b) { //notice how this function is being returned
    if (keys.length == ...
  }
}
```

---

If you don't understand how `sortbyMultipleKeys` works, I suggest to read about 'closures'.

For example, when you do

```
console.log(sortbyMultipleKeys(["alpha", "year"]))
```

you'll see that a function is printed.

```
/* prints: ƒ (a, b) {
    if (keys.length == 0) return;
    key = keys[0];
    if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
    else if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
    else return sortbyMultipleKeys(keys.slice(1))(a, b);
  } */
```

Notice that `keys` variable exists in the function even though it is only accessible in the `sortbyMultipleKeys` scope. But this runs perfectly thanks to closures. And it's probably the most essential part of this code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function:

```
hi = (s) => "hi from " + s
```

this lets us define:

```
() => hi('a')
```

what happens when we do this?

```
(() => hi('a'))()
```

or this:

```
(() => hi)()('a')
```

They all output the same thing? A function is just a thing. JavaScript lets you return things. The method invocation operator `()` invokes functions. It lets you retrieve what's inside of them.